# rails - NameError (undefined local variable or method while using has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails app gives following error:

> NameError (undefined local variable or method 'fac_allocs' for #):
>     app/models/room.rb:4:in ''
>     app/models/room.rb:1:in ''
>     app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb:3:in 'index'

`room.rb` file

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :fac_allocs
  has_many :facs, :through => fac_allocs
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your *associations instead of fac_allocs you need to use a symbol because rails is looking a variable or method named fac_allocs **instead of your associated model***

```
has_many :facs, through: :fac_allocs
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :fac_allocs
  has_many :facs, :through => :fac_allocs
end
```